# Blender 2.8 switches my computer off

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I'm working on dell i3 ram 2gb, HDD, amda 1gb gfx. My laptop previously had battery failure, I work with the charger plugged in all the time. If the charger gets disconnected. My pc turns off. Recently opening a sculpt blend file and dollying (middle mouse) is causing my pc turnoff. Not sure what turns it off, but it's happening when I open blender. I upgraded my ram from 2 to 6. but still the problem exists. I'm thinking of replacing the battery, will that help? Please help me. I love blender2.80

Comment: That is extremely odd. Is it possible it's overheating? How quickly does it turn off?

Comment: Could it be that your charger doesn't provide enough power to sustain working under full load?